# Wordpress blog post url not redirecting to posts

Tags: wordpress

I am not very sure if this is the right place to post the problem since it may not be programmatic thing. My site which is a blog at windowsvj.com has some weird error. When i click on any post url, it says

The requested URL /wpblog/2012/07/resolve-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client-error-on-windows-8/ was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Can anyone suggest what must be wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems this is SEF urls problem. In the Dashboard, under Settings, check out permalinks options.

Comment: hi thanks for answering. So i was palying with .htaccess and xmlrpc recently.. can that be an issue ?

Comment: Yes. It can be coz of `.htaccess`.

Comment: congrats, seems you solved it :)

Comment: Yes i did it.. thanks a lot how can i mark this as answered

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. But I re-posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this is SEF urls problem. In the Dashboard, under Settings, check out permalinks options.

Also, playing with `.htaccess` could cause the problem.

Comment: i installed wordpress module on bitnami LAMP stack. Only index url was working where list of all posts is shown. Clicking on individual posts return a 404 error saying URL not found. But after changing Permalinks Setting, saving the settings and creating a new post, I was able to open that new Post link also